# React native : import from a distant directory (and got an error)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, import

I put all my images in a folder at the root of my project and I'm using them in the code that I write.
Howether there seems to be an error (ex : `Cannot find module '../../../assets/Structure.png' or its corresponding type declarations` because of:
`import structure from "../../../assets/Structure.png";`
). It still work when I do my `yarn start` but it seems to be a potential issue. Any idea of how to make it work without error? The issue seems to be with the '../'.
My project is like this :

> src --> pages --> page1 --> index.tsx

> assets --> image.png

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to create `aliases` to your folders which can be easily imported without any hassle.

Open `babel.config.js` situated in the root folder and add the following lines of settings

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        root: ["./src"],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.svg', '.png', '.jpg','.tsx','.ts'],
        alias: {
          "assets":"./src/assets"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

Now you can easily import any assets like

`assets/Structure.png` without using ../../../ it will make your life easier..

You should similarly set up aliases for other common folders.

Make sure to completely re-run the application..

Cheers.